# Как открыть блокнот с содержимым RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть код, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\Поздравь друзей!.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
string Path = "C:\\Поздравь друзей!.txt";
Process.Start(Path);
```

При нажатии на кнопку у меня открывается пустой блокнот. А если ещё раз нажать, то откроется уже с содержимым `richTextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

В документации ни слова об этом, но выглядит так, будто метод SaveFile асинхронный... поэтому если блокнот запускается "слишком быстро", то файл ещё не записан.

**UPD**

Можно попробовать старый добрый sleep в качестве костыля. Или копать в дебрях .NET документации на предмет того, где написано об асинхронности записи и, может, способ синхронизации с ним. В общем, как всегда MS радует.

В качестве второго костыля можно попробовать опрашивать файл и как только он перестанет расти - открывать блокнот.

Comment: И как это исправить? Чтобы при запуске текст уже был там.

Comment: Ага все получилось, все заработало как надо) Спасибо.

Comment: Что именно получилось?

Comment: При наводе на кнопку файл создается, а при её нажатии открывается, и все отображается.